# Storing large files in git without copying

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm looking for a way to store large files efficiently in git without having multiple local copies.

I've tried git lfs, however it creates a copy in `.git/lfs/objects/` of every modified file on every commit. This means that I need at least twice as much disk space (if I use `git lfs prune` regularly).

I understand that this is to keep the git workflow, but my data is in the hundreds of GBs and this is not really usable.

Answer (score 1):

Git is designed and optimized for storing text files that can be versioned over time. Because of this, it has historically come up rather short when dealing with large binary files. While git LFS is a great way to integrate the storage of large binaries into a git workflow, it is still not what git was designed for.

By the nature of how LFS in implemented, keeping local copies of large files is impossible to avoid. Fundamentally it's just a mechanism for connecting git directly to a binary file archive.

If you're dealing in binaries to the tune of hundreds of gigabytes, git is probably not the right tool for your needs. (Well, maybe for any text files stored in your projects.) But you may be trying to ram a square peg into a round hole.

As an architect buddy of mine says, "When all you have is a hammer, everything starts to look like a screw."

I deal almost exclusively in source code, so I can't really make a concrete recommendation beyond saying check out document management systems designed for media artifacts.

If you're certain you want to stick with git, you might be able to build a mechanism similar to a package manager to pull down the artifacts you require on demand based using a configuration and script you can store in your repo.

Comment: The idea I have in my head is to store just version information and how to retrieve the files in the repo (like git lfs), but kind of ignore the git workflow and retrieve/upload the binary files with a separate command. It's not very convenient, but it seems useful in some cases and I'm surprised that I couldn't find such a tool and that's why I posted my question

Comment: That's basically how many people handled this before git-lfs. There are many tools built that work the way you envision it working, but they are intended for managing packages (maven, nuget, npm, etc), or build artifacts (Artifactory, Archiva, Nexus, etc). Can you tell us what type of data you're working with? It might help us in offering guidance.

Comment: Yes, my research turned up Artifactory/Nexus and of the course the package management systems. My data is huge text files (most of them compressed with gzip), containing gene sequence variations. The format is usually VCF(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Call_Format) or pretty similar.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like in your situation, storing them in an artifact repository will probably be your best bet if you want to stick with git. Of course, storage is cheap, so git-lfs might be a more cost effective solution even if you have to expand the storage on your machine.

Comment: Upgrading storage is not really possible - we have AWS instances that we don't manage and it's difficult to convince people to allocate 500 GB more because of how git-lfs works.

Anyway, I think I found a solution finally - https://github.com/foursquare/gitshed